# Add new route example.com/username while preserving existing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to have `example.com/username` while preserving `example.com/users/1` route?

To put simply, I just need to link to users's profile via username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an arbitrary route like this using:

```
get "/:username" => "users#show", as: :username
```

This will pass the username as a parameter to the show action.

Then in your views:

```
<%= link_to user.name, username_path(username: user.username) %>
```

You'll also need a controller action that knows how to handle the `username` parameter. If you want to use your existing users controller and preserve your `/users/:id` URLs too, you could do something like:

```
def show
  @user = if params[:username].present?
    User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  else
    User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the response. This is exactly what I need but there is one problem. How do I preserve my other routes? Like **site.com/products**? Is there way to add an exception or maybe add a catch all route?

Comment: As it turned out I could place the route at the very bottom so it is evaluated last.

Comment: Yep. It is probably also a good idea to put some restrictions on the username parameter's format (e.g. usernames probably can't include a /) using [the `constraints` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints).